# How do I grep to find a file only matching a string enclosed with wildcards

Tags: shell-script

I have to find a file with only a given number and a string. Ito find **856** enclosed with wildcards `*856*`.

e.g. I have this **fileA.txt** with thousands of numbers:

```
45423542354235423542
5423543542353254235
345435245243
435435345
452345345
4523543455454
```

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

findFile() {
    while read -r LINE
    do
         printf "$LINE\n"
         grep -il "$LINE" *856*
         printf "\n"
    done < /path/to/fileA.txt > /path/to/result.txt
}

findFile
```

**EDIT:** The file names doesn't contain the pattern from `fileA.txt`.

Desired output:

```
45423542354235423542
found_file_856_COMPANY_FFW3443E.dat

5423543542353254235
found_file_856_COMPANY_43R43F.dat

345435245243
found_file_856_COMPANY_77Y85HHH.dat

435435345
found_file_856_COMPANY_64Y76H6.dat

452345345
found_file_856_COMPANY_9630GGTFVF.dat

4523543455454
found_file_856_COMPANY_2R98JD925.dat
```

Comment: (I can comment now!) Is there unwanted trailing whitespace in your fileA.txt? If so you can trim with `CLEANLINE = $( echo "$LINE" | sed 's/[\t ]*$//' )`

Comment: fileA.txt has the numbers needed to find the files I'm looking for. Meaning each number in fileA.txt is equal to one file. Take a look at the example content of fileA.txt. It has six numbers, meaning I'm looking for six files. My script is good, but I'm just stuck with 856 as when you put it inside a script it starts not to read the * or the wildcard. That's my problem now. If I get through that, I'm good to go.

Comment: Did my latest comment on my answer help? Adding the full path sounds like it might be the ticket.

Comment: I decided to call the script from another script. Like I'm doing while loop to execute the script e.g. `source /path/to/script.sh pattern` is being executed by while loop. It's working now but it could be better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no filename has newlines in them...

Create a list of the "`856`-files" and use `grep` to filter out the ones you want:

```
find . -name '*856*' > filelist
grep -Ff fileA.txt filelist >result.txt
```

The `grep` command will use the strings in `fileA.txt` as patterns and will extract the names from `filelist` that matches these.  The `-F` flag will ensure that the strings in `fileA.txt` are interpreted as fixed strings (not as regular expressions).

The patterns in `fileA.txt` may have to be made more specific, for example by prefixing them with `_` and adding the `.dat` suffix:

```
sed -e 's/^/_/' -e 's/$/.dat' fileA.txt >fileB.txt
```

You would then use `fileB.txt` with the `grep` instead of `fileA.txt`.

Comment: I chose `grep` because it's way faster than `find`. I think my only problem in my script is `*856*` as `*` is not being read as a wildcard. My script, doesn't output the grep command but it outputs when I type it directly as `$ grep -il 'some_pattern_here' *856*`. Really need help. I'm doing three thousand to five thousand files to find. It's really hard to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking in your question (i.e. what are you trying to achieve?) or which shell you're using. Sadly I don't have the rep. to comment.

Assuming you're using the `bash` shell; if you're trying find a globbing pattern which returns all the files in the current folder containing the string 856 then `*856*` is the correct way.

To clarify, if you want to search for `sausages` inside all files with name containing the string `snacks_for_later` then you would use

```
    $ grep sausages *snacks_for_later*
```

to find any sausages.

---

To check that you're searching within the correct files, you can test your globbing pattern using ls:

```
    $ ls *856*
```

---

If you're not running the commands from the folder the files are in, you would have to use the pattern `/path/to/allfiles/*856*` for both grep and ls. Glob patterns (such as '*') don't traverse directories.

Comment: It doesn't output the files I'm looking for. I'm using BASH

Comment: Are the files you're looking for in the folder where you execute the script or are they scattered around?

Comment: They are in one directory e.g. `/path/to/allfiles/`. I only want to do like this command `grep -il '452352435' *856*` and outputs the file with the `452352435` inside the file. But there are thousands to find and it's really a pain in the ass to do it one by one.

Comment: nothing's happening with `ls *snacks* | grep sausages`. It doesn't output anything.

Comment: Sorry, that approach was to find files such as "snacks_with_sausages.dat", which you've clarified isn't relevant now. Try `ls /path/to/allfiles/*856*`. If this works, update the glob pattern in your script to include the '/path/to/allfiles/' bit.