# How to print the inputted pattern which don't have matching lines?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have this grep command to find files with matching pattern.

```
grep -oiE 'pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4' *pattern_in_a_filename* | sort -u
```

Output:

```
file_one:pattern1
file_two:pattern2
file_two:pattern3
```

What I want is to output the `pattern4` saying that is not being found like this example:

```
file_one:pattern1
file_two:pattern2
file_two:pattern3
pattern4 not found
```

I'm doing thousands of thousands of patterns and it has to be done as quick as possible because these are crucial data needed in our operations.

Comment: what if only one pattern was matched?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Then it will do the same like pattern4.

Comment: `*file_name*` denotes multiple files?

Comment: yup dude! It's saying that there are bunch of different filenames with that pattern in a directory. I'll edit and clarify it for all.

Comment: Can you not just loop over all the patterns?

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now but it takes a lot of time. It takes 20 seconds more or less to just execute 1 pattern and I'm doing an average of 2000-3000+ patterns everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `sh` script that produces the results you need.

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -f /path/to/patterns.txt /path/to/*_856_2017* | sort -u > /path/to/foundFiles.txt 

while read -r LINE
do
    grep -F "$LINE" /path/to/foundFiles.txt
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "$LINE" not found
    fi
done < /path/to/patterns.txt
```

In this script, I assume you output the results of **your** `grep` to the file `found.txt`, and that you store your patterns in the file `/path/to/foundFiles.txt`.

As you can see, the `grep` in the loop will produce the same contents of the file `found.txt` while adding `"$pattern" not found` for the missing ones.

I also devised a second approach to your case:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -f /path/to/patterns.txt /path/to/*_856_2017* |
    sort -u > /path/to/foundFiles.txt

comm -23 /path/to/patterns.txt /path/to/foundFiles.txt |
    xargs -L 1 -I {} echo {} not found > /path/to/notFoundFiles.txt

cat /path/to/foundFiles.txt /path/to/notFoundFiles.txt > /path/to/finalList.txt
```

In this case, `patterns.txt` needs to be already sorted for `comm` to work.

The `comm` command compares the two files returning the lines present only in `patterns.txt` (`-23` parameter), which is the list of patterns not found by `grep`.

Then, `xargs` grabs every line (`-L 1`) and echoes the line (`{}`) with " not found" appended to it. The result of `xargs` is redirected to the `notFoundFiles.txt` file.

Finally, you simply concatenate foundFiles.txt and notFoundFiles.txt into `finalList.txt`.

Comment: Almost the same with my script. But as I said, it takes 20 secs more or less to execute only 1 pattern. Need things to be faster

Comment: This loop runs on the results of your command; it should take like one second total. Did you try it?

Comment: Try to refer on my other question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397402/how-do-i-grep-to-find-a-file-only-matching-a-string-enclosed-with-wildcards My problem with my script is `#!/bin/sh` seems not reading correctly on `*856*` as `*` as wildcard (When it's inside the while loop) Try to run it yourself

Comment: You will need to add the -F parameter to the grep command in my script to treat every pattern as a fixed string.

Comment: And also you did `cat patterns.txt` but you call on `while read -r pattern` which doesn't make sense where did you get that `pattern`. I think you have mistaken `pattern` with `$LINE`.

Comment: You can name the variable pattern, LINE, or anything you want. It’s a variable name. Did you try it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67274/discussion-between-washichawbachaw-and-cesarv).

Answer (score 7):

> it has to be done as **quick** as possible

***Want to get things done as quick as possible?***

Discover **parallel processing** and apply the following GNU **`parallel`** solution:

The right way starts with placing all your patterns into file, let's say `patterns.txt`.

The crucial job:

```
cat patterns.txt | parallel -j 0 --no-notice 'grep -Hoi {} /path/to/files/* || echo "{} not found"' | sort -u
```

- `-j N` - Number of jobslots. Run up to `N` jobs in parallel. `0` means as many as possible. Default is 100% which will run
              one job per CPU core.

---

The above command will search for each *pattern* from `patterns.txt` within all files in parallel.

I've made a test having only **2** CPU cores with some list of patterns and a few csv files of 641 Mb each. And I've got about **470%** time speed increase in comparison with consecutive processing.
The more CPU cores your computer has the more time speed performance you reach.

Make your conclusions ...

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Comment: `-bash: parallel: command not found`. Does it have to be installed? Unfortunately, I don't have a superuser privilege.

Comment: your answer was very good but there's this big problem. when I execute that command, it returns the files with the patterns in it but also it returns all the pattern from `pattern.txt` as `not found`. And that is not good. A little more tweak on the command and your answer will be my best answer

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, it's obvious that new programm should be installed beforehand. Make sure that you are using GNU parallel, check `parallel --version`. As I wrote - I've tested your "scheme" and it worked fine. I suppose that the issue is on your side and you missed something or made some mistakes or your actual conditions differ from those mentioned in the question

Comment: I have this now `GNU parallel 20170922
Copyright (C) 2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017
Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>`

Comment: This what happens after running your command. my patterns.txt has 1800 patterns separated by newline: `parallel: Warning: Only enough file handles to run 252 jobs in parallel.
parallel: Warning: Running 'parallel -j0 -N 252 --pipe parallel -j0' or
parallel: Warning: raising 'ulimit -n' or 'nofile' in /etc/security/limits.conf
parallel: Warning: or /proc/sys/fs/file-max may help.
`

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, this error message may occur if if there is something else running on the system, that uses a lot
of file handles. See this post http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/parallel/2017-07/msg00006.html

Comment: Yes because I am currently running my while loop script at that time. I'm so busy, that I need to run 3-5 scripts at the same time.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, also, check the answer from the author of the `parallel` tool: https://www.mail-archive.com/parallel@gnu.org/msg01612.html

Comment: @WashichawbachaW The warning is a warning only: You should get the correct results. It is simply saying it can only run 252 in parallel. The rest will be run, when the first 252 have finished. If you want to run the 1800 processes in parallel, try the trick: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Running-more-than-250-jobs-workaround

Comment: @OleTange, greetings. Thanks for coopearting

Comment: Thanks guys, your answer was also correct but I give the best answer to @cesarv for helping me all through the process. I will try to use this example and other GNU parallel in my future scripts.

Answer (score 6):

The tool `grep` searches files by patterns.  This means the pattern is the input and the file is the output.  And this means all you can find with grep are files but not patterns.

In order to find those files, which do not contain a matching pattern, you have to invert the search with `-v`. This requires two calls.

Example:

```
$ echo a > xa
$ echo ab > xab
$ echo c > xc
$ { grep -oiE 'a|b' x*; grep -vl -E 'a|b' x*; } | sort -u
xa:a
xab:a
xab:b
xc
```

In order to find those patterns, which did not match, you have to make your patterns the input and the search result the pattern. The list of matches becomes the pattern and the pattern becomes the data, in which you have to search.

Lets assume this may be the pattern for the files from the preceding example.

```
$ pattern='a|b|d'
```

Then this stores the list of matching patterns in an array:

```
$ found=($(grep -hoiE "$pattern" x* | sort -u))
```

And this converts the array into the new pattern:

```
$ new_pattern="$(IFS='|' ; echo "${found[*]}")"
```

And this converts the original pattern into data:

```
$ data="${pattern//|/$'\n'}"
```

Then this is the list of patterns, which did not match:

```
$ grep -viE "$new_pattern" <<< "$data"
d
```

Comment: Can you have an example which makes the patterns inside a txt file?

Comment: `pattern=$(cat pattern.txt)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to achieve what you expect.
Since you stated that you have thousands of patterns, so I'm assuming you feed *patterns* from a file, then that's much better than passing direct *patterns* to `grep`. The command is as following.

```bsh
grep -oif ../patt_file file* && 
    printf "%s Not Found.\n" $(grep -vFxf <(grep -oihf ../patt_file file*) \
    <(< ../patt_file))
```

To avoid matching *patterns* file `patt_file` itself, you need to move it to different directory than where your input `infiles*` are there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this tomorrow when I get back to work

Comment: this will print `Not Found.\n` even if all patterns were found which is not pretty good